Incan-style people execute intruders by dipping them in gold

Movie was set in a wild west style location.
Heroine was a blonde cowgirl. Her name was Rainbow, or something similarly derived from nature.
Heroine has a male companion who is a womanizer. He's infatuated with a local saloon girl/gold digger.
The title sequence introduces the cast of characters. Each shot has the character standing mid-screen and posing for the viewer. Subtitles below gave their name and a brief description. Played somewhat for laughs.
The two are looking for some sort of hidden treasure.
The Heroine finds a hidden city with Incan-style architecture and people. She finds out that she's the lost princess of the tribe, and decides to stay with them. Her male companion decides to leave her and wish her good luck.
Shortly after, the Heroine discovers that the tribe practices human sacrifice. They take out the heart of the victim then dip them in molten gold. Her parents' statues turn out to be their gold plated corpses. The head priest/chief attempts to kill her similarly. An earlier scene shows the tribe capturing an intruder, sewing his mouth shut, then dipping him alive in the molten gold.
Her companion arrives just in time to save her.
I saw the movie in the 80's, but can definitely be older.
English language movie, but had a dubbed spaghetti western feel.


Every "identify-this-movie" question should look like this one :-)

Sounds like Yellow Hair and the Fortress of Gold from 1984:

Fiery blonde half-breed Yellow Hair and her easygoing sidekick the Pecos Kid are after a fortune in Mayan gold. The courageous duo have run-ins with an army of Mexican soldiers, a gang of dastardly bandits, and a lethal tribe of Aztec warriors while searching the countryside for said gold fortune. 

The tribe dips people in liquid gold and the Pecos Kid saves her near the end just as they're about to sacrifice her. Also, the movie's opening credits are exactly as you describe them: the characters pause and smile as their names and humorous descriptions appear on-screen and this is all accompanied by an actual laugh track. Here's the trailer:



